# jQuery add class when scroll down and remove when scroll up

Tags: jquery, scroll, switch-statement, addclass

So I have this bit of code to turn some lights on when scroll is past a 1000px and if the scroll back up it turns the lights off again, This is done by just adding a class and removing the class..

```
var lights = jQuery('.scene2 .lights');
jQuery(function () {
    lights.data('switch', 'on');
});
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        if (jQuery(lights).data('switch') == 'on') {
            jQuery(lights).data('switch', 'off');
            jQuery(lights).stop().removeClass('lightsOff');
            jQuery(lights).stop().addClass('lightsOn');
        }
    } else {
        if (jQuery(lights).data('switch') == 'off') {
            jQuery(lights).data('switch', 'on');
            jQuery(lights).stop().removeClass('lightsOn');
            jQuery(lights).stop().addClass('lightsOff');
        }
    }
});
```

but I need to do this multiple times & its just alot of code, I was wondering if there is a shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       $('selector').addClass('classname');
   } else {
      // upscroll code
       $('selector').removeClass('classname');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: This sadly didnt help, but thank you! I am now using arrays to minimise the amount of code.